# RubyOnRails tutorial: sample_app no delete link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm on step 10.4.2 and coded the delete link and no delete links appear? I tried logging out and back in to no avail. I see no errors on the server.

Added this:

```
<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
```

I figured it out- it wasn't in the html code- it was that I wasn't logged in as the current admin person who has authority to delete-

```
current_user.admin?
```

Comment: Are you and admin?